# How to delete a file ONLY AFTER it has been downloaded from google colaboratory

Tags: python, file, download, google-colaboratory, delete-file

I am trying to download a file from google colab and delete it after downloading it.

This is my code

```
from google.colab import files
import os
import numpy as np


dir_to_zip = 'FOLDER_NAME'

os.mkdir('/content/' + dir_to_zip)
os.chdir('/content/' + dir_to_zip)


################################################################################
# MAKING FILES
np.savetxt('a.csv', np.array([3, 5, 6, 76]), delimiter=",")
np.savetxt('b.csv', np.array([3, 590, 6, 76]), delimiter=",")

################################################################################
os.chdir('/content')
output_filename = dir_to_zip + '.zip'
print('output', output_filename)
os.system( "zip -r {} {}".format(output_filename, dir_to_zip))

files.download(output_filename)
os.system("rm -r {}".format(dir_to_zip))
os.system("rm -r {}".format(output_filename))
```

In the code I am deleting the `.zip` file after downloading it, but it is not being downloaded. and I am getting this

[image]

Colab deleted the file before downloading/fully downloaded it even though downloading happens before deleting in code.

When I try to do it as 2 cells and run both one after the other, colab deletes the file before downloading and I get the same results.

cell 1:

```
from google.colab import files
import os
import numpy as np


dir_to_zip = 'FOLDER_NAME'

os.mkdir('/content/' + dir_to_zip)
os.chdir('/content/' + dir_to_zip)


################################################################################
# MAKING FILES
np.savetxt('a.csv', np.array([3, 5, 6, 76]), delimiter=",")
np.savetxt('b.csv', np.array([3, 590, 6, 76]), delimiter=",")

################################################################################
os.chdir('/content')
output_filename = dir_to_zip + '.zip'
print('output', output_filename)
os.system( "zip -r {} {}".format(output_filename, dir_to_zip))

files.download(output_filename)
os.system("rm -r {}".format(dir_to_zip))
```

cell 2:

```
os.system("rm -r {}".format(output_filename))
```

It is possible to WAIT FOR SOME TIME and run the second cell after downloading the file but is there an automatic way?

Is there a way to make colab delete a file only after it has downloaded and make it automatic instead of me waiting for it to be completely downloaded?

Thanks

Comment: the only idea: run loop which check if downloaded file has the same size as file on server - and delete when both hat the same size..

Comment: other idea: you would have to check if download can work with `file-like` objects - and then you could use `io.BytesIO()` to create file-like object in memory, and use module `zipfile` to compress to this file-like object in memory, and later download data from this file-like object. This way you don't have to create file on disk and you don't have to delete it.